# In search of pendingIntent triggered when Incoming Phone call -Android

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I'd like the system to trigger my pendingIntent when the phone is off hook on Android devices, is this possible ?  I would use the pendingIntent with an IntentService to do some work off the main thread.  This would be a battery saver for the end user.

Its very similar to how you can pass a pendingIntent to the AlarmManager, I'd like to pass one to the system and let it trigger when it encounters an incoming call.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use telephonymanager, just make a class that listens PhoneStateListener

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    uiReference.defaultRecipient = incomingNumber;
    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
    } else if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
    } else if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: thanks i know about this already ....hopefully it can help another member.  I was hoping that when the device is off hook a pendingIntent could get generated and i could register a IntentService to be called when the pendingIntent is thrown.  i cant find anyhing on this though.